# CSS :last-child selector being ignored by last child

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

HTML:

```
<body>
      <h1>First heading</h1>
      <h1>Second heading</h1>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
h1:last-child{
   color: blue;}
```

So the problem is that the last h1(Second Heading) is not getting styled, although it`s the last child of its parent(body). This issue occurs with "a" and other tags too, but work perfectly fine with "p".

Comment: are you testing the code locally or using online tools like codepen?

Comment: :last-child is a pseudo-class that selects the target element if it is the last child of some other element. That is, :last-child will match the element only if it is the last child of its parent. So in your example, the h1 would have to be the last child in <body>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that in your HTML or IDE, the second `h1` is not the last child.

Here's how it looks in jsFiddle:

[image]

The body element has four children, and the last child is a script element.

So to make it work, you would have to remove all other elements or, in this case, select the third from the last child. [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/orydnm53/)

Answer (score 2):

Try Enclosing your `H1` tag within a `div`

```css
 h1:last-child{
          color:blue;
        }
```

```html
     <body>
      <div>
          <h1>First heading</h1>
          <h1>Second heading</h1>
      </div>
    </body>
```